# rove that the group $G*G'$ presented by $(A \cup A'|R \cup R')$ satisfies the universal property for the coproduct of G and $G'$ in **Grp**.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $(A|R)$, resp. $(A'|R')$, be a presentation for a group G resp. $G'$ we may assume that A, $A'$ are disjoint. Prove that the group $G*G'$ presented by $(A \cup A'|R \cup R')$ satisfies the universal property for the coproduct of G and $G'$ in **Grp**.

**Hint:** Use the universal property of both free groups and quotients to contruct natural homomorphisms $G \rightarrow G*G'$, $G' \rightarrow G*G'$.

Comment: Have you given these a try? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: For example, can you suggest definitions of the natural homomorphisms $G \to G*G'$ and $G' \to G*G'$?